# How can I test errors like 400 , 403 , 500 in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I test my `customErrors statusCode` 403,400 and 500 in asp.net web applications ??

**Web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404error.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="403error.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="400error.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="500error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

I tested 404 error by editng url and creating a false page response on click etc , I dont know how to test other statusCodes.! so, How can I test customErrors ? 
Am a beginner, so sorry for the silly question..

Comment: In one of your endpoints, throw an error or exception

Comment: Use the HttpResponseMessage class to throw the http response codes that your interested to the client.

Comment: can you guys help me with any tutorial website for this.!!

Comment: That's not really "allowed" per the Help Center. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx) reference for HttpException does have some sample code, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: okey !! Thanks everyone  .

Comment: throw an HttpException somewhere in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw a new [HttpException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bazc3hww.aspx):

```
throw new HttpException(400, "This is a 'bad request' test");
```

Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

I like Robs IDea.
You could simply add an TestController which implements a bunch of methods for raising the exceptions.
I would add an ifdef in the routing so that these kinds of endpoints are only available during testing, not in production.

Comment: The question is not tagged as an ASP.NET MVC question, so this might not be entirely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fake controller with actions for each of the things you want to test.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult BadRequest()
    {
          throw new HttpException(400, "Bad request");
    }

    public ActionResult Unauthorized()
    {
          throw new HttpException(403, "Unauthorized");
    }

    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
          throw new HttpException(500, "Server error");
    }        
}
```

Comment: The question is not tagged as an ASP.NET MVC question, so this might not be entirely relevant.

Comment: Interesting to see the method names..!! 400()

Comment: Method names were for display purposes. Fixed them